# Getting the Driver Details the same as Driver File Details Window

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to duplicate the exact file listing below which is found under "Driver Details" in Device Manager, i've come up with the below code but i'm unable to display this list.  Any help is awesome.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");

foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
{
    if(obj["DriverProviderName"] != null)

        foreach (PropertyData prop in obj.Properties)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\driverusers.txt", prop.Name +"\t" +prop.Value+"\n");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
        }
}
```

[image: Driver FIle details]

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Comment: Every question i've ever asked i've always put that in it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, someone was doing something very similar.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63149-devices-in-c%23/

The first thing I can think of is to go hunt for it in the registry. (I think they even state this in the article above).

Also, check this out:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: Nick https://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/ does EXACTLY what i want but the source isnt available

Comment: In that case, take a look at this:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/217155/get-a-list-of-installed-drivers

Comment: I'll do some more hunting around, but I'm pretty sure this kind of thing has been done before and should be available somewhere.

Everything I can see is playing around with WMI in one form or another.

Comment: the path name lists the .sys but not all the .inf associated with it

Comment: any luck finding something? I have the same problem.